# What is "httpcore._exceptions.ConnectTimeout: timed out" error supposed to mean? How would I fix it?

Tags: python, api, google-translate

Basically, I'm using google translate API to translate a few documents that need to be translated into as many languages as possible, phrase by phrase. It had worked previously without any hassle, but when I use it now I keep getting this error.

```
httpcore._exceptions.ConnectTimeout: timed out
```

the line in which this error is happening is:

```
word = Translator().translate(word_list[untrans_word], src=user_first_lang, dest=lang_to_translate_to)
```

This `word` variable is in a function that translates the word and processes such that it fits into a list properly. `untrans_word` is the untranslated word that needs to be translated. The rest of the program works fine. I know this as I've tried this before and it has worked smoothly. What could be the problem, and how do I fix it?

The documentation of [Google Translate API python library](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/).

Comment: Check your connection. May your VPN or proxy blocking the network

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue. Re-run will fix it. This is not an official google cloud API which means google can any time closes the door. I have tried "try" and "close file" methods to save the content already translated and found not worth it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).