# Googletrans throws a ConnectTimeout error (the handshake operation timed out)

Tags: python, google-translate

I am currently working on a translator in Python 3.8.5 but I am not getting an appropriate result.
My code thus far is

```
from googletrans import Translator

text = '''Vous êtes français'''
translator = Translator()
dt = translator.detect(text)
print(dt)
```

In my terminal, I should be getting the source and the destination
which is fr for Source and en for `dt` but instead what I am getting is this error I have no idea how to fix.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Akash/Desktop/Learning python/Project10-MegaProject-Translator.py", line 5, in <module>
    dt = translator.detect(text)
  File "C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 255, in detect
    data = self._translate(text, 'en', 'auto', kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 78, in _translate
    token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
  File "C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 194, in do
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 54, in _update
    r = self.client.get(self.host)
  File "C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 755, in get
    return self.request(
  File "C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 600, in request
    return self.send(
  File "C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 620, in send
    response = self.send_handling_redirects(
  File "C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 647, in send_handling_redirects
    response = self.send_handling_auth(
  File "C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 684, in send_handling_auth
    response = self.send_single_request(request, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 714, in send_single_request
    ) = transport.request(
  File "C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\connection_pool.py", line 152, in request
    response = connection.request(
  File "C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\connection.py", line 65, in request
    self.socket = self._open_socket(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\connection.py", line 85, in _open_socket
    return self.backend.open_tcp_stream(
  File "C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_backends\sync.py", line 139, in open_tcp_stream
    return SyncSocketStream(sock=sock)
  File "C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_exceptions.py", line 12, in map_exceptions
    raise to_exc(exc) from None
httpcore._exceptions.ConnectTimeout: _ssl.c:1106: The handshake operation timed out
PS C:\Users\Akash\Desktop\Learning python>
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate, no answers there, though: [what is “httpcore._exceptions.ConnectTimeout: timed out” error supposed to mean? how would I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62870783/7851470)

Comment: Check your connection. May your VPN or proxy  blocking the network

Answer (score 3):

The [googletrans API](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) that you are using is the same service as translate.google.com. Unfortunately if you send to much requests using googletrans, your IP will be blocked by google. As this service is not intended to translate a bulk of data. Also in in the [documentation of googletrans API](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#note-on-library-usage) it mentioned the following problems.

> **Note on library usage**:
>
> 1. The maximum character limit on a single text is 15k.
> 2. Due to limitations of the web version of google translate, this API
>    does not guarantee that the library would work properly at all
>    times. (so please use this library if you don’t care about
>    stability.)
> 3. If you want to use a stable API, I highly recommend you to use
>    Google’s official translate API.
> 4. If you get HTTP 5xx error or errors like #6, it’s probably because
>    Google has banned your client IP address.

I suggest to use the [official Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs) for you to utilize the full potential of the API.

Comment: so do you mean that my google trans is not working because i am sending a bulk of data to translate and i have to use the official translate api but i dont know how to do that is it something like From google trans import official translate api or is it like importing something  else so kindly i would appreciate if you added a piece of code to show how to use it.

Comment: @HellDenGaming You can check this on how to set up [Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup) afterwards you can try this [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/quickstart). You can browse this [site](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/how-to) for other guides that have sample code.