# Googletrans Error- The handshake operation timed out

Tags: python, tkinter, google-translation-api, googletrans

When I try to translate text using the googletrans module, I get an error:

```
httpcore._exceptions.ConnectTimeout: _ssl.c:1106: The handshake operation timed out
```

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from googletrans import Translator , LANGUAGES

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

def translate():
    translator = Translator()
    translated_text = translator.translate(text=entry.get(),
                                           dest=languages_listbox.get(languages_listbox.curselection())) # Text does not get get translated and it throws an error
    output_label.config(text = f"Translated Text: {translated_text}")

entry = Entry(root , font = "consolas 14")
entry.place(x = 120 , y = 0)

entry.insert(0 , "Hello world")

languages_list = []

for key, value in LANGUAGES.items():
    languages_list.append(value)

languages_listbox_frame = Frame(root)
languages_listbox_frame.place(x = 120 , y = 50)

languages_listbox = Listbox(languages_listbox_frame , font = "calibri 14")
languages_listbox.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(languages_listbox_frame , orient = VERTICAL , command = languages_listbox.yview)
scrollbar.grid(row = 0 , column = 1 , sticky = N+S+E+W)

languages_listbox.config(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)

for language in languages_list:
    languages_listbox.insert(END , language)

languages_listbox.select_set(0)

translate_button = Button(root , text = "Translate" , font = "comicsansms 18 bold" , command = translate)
translate_button.place(x = 160 , y = 370)

output_label = Label(root , text = "Translated Text: " , font = "comicsansms 16 bold")
output_label.place(x = 5 , y = 460)

mainloop()
```

My code is very simple and I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

I tried changing the network connection, but it made no difference.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: Seems like your making too much requests to the API, and it has blocked your IP address.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65279841/13382000

Comment: It looks like tkinter is completely unrelated to the problem. I recommend you make a [mcve] that just has the call to the translator, and a hard-coded value for the inputs. Get that working before trying to get it working in a GUI.

Comment: @CoolCloud: If it blocks my IP address if I make too many requests, is there any other module or library that I can use to translate text?

Comment: Check : https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs

Comment: @CoolCloud: Is there any tutorial or sample code given in the link that you mentioned? I am asking this because I couldn't find any.

Comment: Which language are you translating from.

Comment: @CoolCloud: English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well that seems very much like an API error as google does not like when you send too much request, I cannot close this question either as the answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65279841/googletrans-throws-a-connecttimeout-error-the-handshake-operation-timed-out) is not an accepted one, anyway here is an alternative using `deep_translator`.

- Start by installing it:

```
pip install deep-translator
```

- Now I recommend you take a stroll down its [docs](https://pypi.org/project/deep-translator/), but ill include an example using Google Translate anyway. Start by importing it:

```
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator
```

- Now create an initial instance of it, just to get the language map.

```
translator = GoogleTranslator(target='en')

languages_list = []
lang_map = translator.get_supported_languages(as_dict=True) # Get in form of dict

for key, value in lang_map.items():
    languages_list.append(key.title()) # Making first letter capital with title()
```

- Now for the translation part, change your function to the following:

```
def translate():
    lang = lang_map[languages_listbox.get(languages_listbox.curselection()[0]).lower()] # Get the corresponding language code from the dictionary    
    translator = GoogleTranslator(source='en',target=lang) # Create new instance with selected language
    translated_text = translator.translate(entry.get()) # Translate
    
    output_label.config(text = f"Translated Text: {translated_text}") # Update the text
```

Yes creating a new instance every time function is run is not a good idea, but I couldn't find another successful method to change the target language once it is initially set. It does not seem to give any error as of now, unless your `source` and `target` languages are both same.

On a side note, it is better to use `threading`, as sometimes the API might take time to respond and it will freeze the GUI.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am facing one issue with `deep_translator`; so can you please help me out? The problem is that, the translation is not working for all languages. For example, if I try to translate the string `'Hello, how are you?'` to `Irish` language, The output is the same and does the text does not get translated properly.

Comment: @Lenovo360 Well I am not sure, I did not know about `deep_translator` till you asked this question. I did some research and found out about it and started using it up to adapt with your code. I had also tried a few other libraries, but none worked. I am not familiar with why it is behaving as such.